# I want toggle theme on main page with button from imported component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a toggle button on my main page app.js to switch themes dark/light and everything works fine. Now I try to put button inside my  component and use it from that page imported in app.js and i can't figure how to make that working...

Is it possible to insert a button into the nav component and use it on the main page to change the theme

```
    const getBackground = style('mode', {
  light: "#eee",
  dark : "hsl(207, 26%, 17%)"
});

const getBackground2 = style('mode', {
  light: "#eee",
  dark : "hsl(209, 23%, 22%)"
});

const getForeground = style('mode', {
  light: "hsl(207, 26%, 17%)",
  dark : "#eee"
});

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
body {
  background-color : ${getBackground};
}
.country, nav, input, select, .back {
  background-color : ${getBackground2};
}
.info_container p, .info_container h2, nav, ::placeholder, .search_countries input, .search_countries::after, .select_countries::after, select, .info-state, .back span {
  color : ${getForeground};
}
`
function getInitialTheme () {
  const savedTheme = storage.getItem('theme');
  return savedTheme ? JSON.parse(savedTheme) : {mode: 'light'};
}

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(getInitialTheme);

  useEffect(()=>{
    storage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme))
  },[theme]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Router>
    <>
    <GlobalStyle/>
    <div className="App">
      <Nav></Nav>
      <button className="theme" onClick={e => setTheme(theme.mode === 'dark' ? {mode : 'light'} : {mode : 'dark'})}>toggle theme</button>
      <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={UbaciZemlje} />
      <Route path="/JednaZemljaInfo" exact component={JednaZemljaInfo} />
      <Route path="/JednaZemljaInfo/:name" component={JednaZemljaInfo} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </>
    </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please add more details about your component where you are adding the button and app.js

Comment: this upload cod is part of app.js component, and i want but button from that page inside nav component

Answer (score 0):

create a new component for changing the theme now put your all theme related logic in that component. I assume that you will show your theme changing button on header so create a header component and put this theme changing component in to header component. now you need to just include your header component in your app.js

Answer (score 0):

From your question comment, I can say what you want is

This is inside your Nav component
`<button className="theme" onClick={this.props.setTheme}>toggle theme</button>`

Inside your app.js
`/*the state should know the theme for potential theme update*/
state = {theme: {mode: 'dark'}};`

Then render
`<Nav setTheme={(theme)=> this.setState(this.setTheme(theme))} />`

and define setTheme method in app.js as follows

`setTheme = theme => {(theme.mode === 'dark')? {mode:'light'} : {mode:'dark'}};`

Comment: I do all this stuff from some tutorial from internet and all works but i want customize little bit. I have nav component and my nav will show up on all other pages inside nav is my header and i want that button for toggle theme put in that header...but all staff for change theme are on app.js page

Comment: i update code now u can see clearly, now i want that button put inside my nav component and from there toggle theme if that possible